# "o mais" e "mais", o uso dos comparativos e superlativos

Tags: gramática, superlativos

> Esse bolo é mais gostoso.
>
> Esse bolo é o mais gostoso.

Se eu entendi direito, as duas sentenças aqui estão certas, e a diferença entre as duas é que na primeira, o significado é que ele é mais gostoso do que um outro, e na segunda ele é o mais gostoso que existe, ou o mais gostoso na padaria etc.

Mas tem outras formas.  Por exemplo:

> O bolo mais gostoso é esse aqui.

Não dá pra dizer "O bolo o mais gostoso" né?  Pra mim parece que falar assim seria errado, mas talvez eu esteja errando e seja certo mesmo...

Se eu nem estou, parece que nesse contexto não dá pra ver se é comparativo ou superlativo.  Há um jeito pra diferenciar entre os dois assim, ou é indeterminado mesmo?

Existe também

> o bolo que é o mais gostoso é esse aqui
>
> o bolo que é mais gostoso é esse aqui

Mas na maioria dos casos, acho que não seja tão natural...

Comment: Boa pergunta! Eu sempre sentia que faz falta no português mais distinção entre o comparativo e o superlativo. (Quanto mais no crioulo onde, não usando o artigo, são homónimos!) Mas, com tempo, começou a pensar que esta distinção pode ser menos útil que parece, visto que o superlativo é ambíguo sem contexto, e o comparativo pode servir no lugar do superlativo ("mais X do que os outros"). Há ambiguidade, sem dúvida, mas agora tenho dúvida de até qual ponte essa distinção reduz a ambiguidade.

Comment: @Dan Eu não falo crioulo, mas imagino que eles se arranjem de alguma maneira? Tudo pode ser ambíguo sem contexto. Podes substituir o superlativo pelo comparativo do modo que dizes, mas em muitos casos eu não o faria. Eu digo *X foi **o melhor marcador** do campeonato* e não *X foi **melhor marcador que qualquer dos outros** no campeonato*

Comment: er than = mais que, the est = o mais

Answer (score 2):

As seguintes são corretas:

- Esse bolo é mais gostoso.
- Esse bolo é o mais gostoso.
- O bolo mais gostoso é esse.

Sem contexto, o último exemplo é ambíguo. Mas na realidade sempre existe contexto, seja explícito ou implícito. O contexto pode ser dado pela situação mesma, pela relação dos falantes (se eles se conhecem é mais provável que eles possam adivinhar o que o outro quis dizer), por pequenas mudanças na sintaxe...

Se duas pessoas estão diante de uma mesa com meia dúzia de bolos e uma delas diz "O bolo mais gostoso é esse", é provável que ela queira dizer "O bolo mais gostoso dessa mesa é esse aqui" (e também é provável que aponte o dedo ao bolo). Não é muito provável que queira dizer "O bolo mais gostoso do mundo é esse", nem "O bolo mais gostoso que eu tenho feito na minha vida inteira é esse". Tais interpretações só seriam razoáveis se as duas pessoas tivessem estado falando desse jeito (sobre os bolos mais gostosos do mundo ou das suas experiências culinárias) até então.

Comment: Para mim, a 2ª e 3ª frases são equivalentes. A  1ª é tão ou mais problemática que as outras. Se chegássemos à mesa e me dissesses, *esse bolo é mais gostoso*, eu perguntaria de imediato, *mais gostoso que o quê?* Faria sentido se eu elogiasse ou me preparasse para comer o bolo A; então já seria claro se dissesses, *o bolo B é mais gostoso*.

Comment: @Jacinto Certo. Mas novamente é questão de contexto. Tenho que supor que enquanto eu pronunciasse a primeira frase, eu estaria olhando o apontando o fazendo alguma coisa para indicar o ponto de comparação.

Comment: Exatamente. Comentei porque discutiste em pormenor a necessidade de contexto para a 3ª, e não disseste nada em relação à primeira.

Answer (score 2):

- **"Esse bolo é mais gostoso"** - Essa frase pode até ter outros significados mas, sem contexto, será mais frequentemente compreendida como um comparativo com outros bolos; "esse bolo é mais gostoso do que outro(s)" e o meu interlocutor sabe quais são os outros.
- **"Esse bolo é o mais gostoso."**- Trata-se de um superlativo, esse bolo é "o mais gostoso de todos" e a pessoa com quem falo sabe quais são "todos".
- **"O bolo mais gostoso é esse aqui."** O mesmo significado da frase anterior.
- **"O bolo... o mais gostoso é esse aqui"** é possível apenas com uma pausa, enquanto aquele que fala decide como vai completar a frase.

As suas últimas frases ("o bolo que é o mais gostoso é esse aqui" e
"o bolo que é mais gostoso é esse aqui"), embora gramaticalmente corretas, não são idiomáticas.  Evite-as a não ser que você queira parecer um alienígena.

Comment: "- Qual é o bolo mais gostoso que você tem?" "- O bolo mais gostoso é este aqui / esse aí / aquele ali" é idiomático, mas obviamente responderiam "Este aqui" "Este" "O de chocolate" pois num diálogo pode se optar pelo mais fácil (com menos palavras)

Answer (score 1):

Sim, a tua distinção entre comparativo e superlativo está correta. As tuas duas primeiras formas de superlativo são equivalentes, embora uma ou outra possa soar mais natural dependendo do contexto. Começando com exemplos mais explícitos (as palavras entre parênteses são opcionais):

> Este bolo é **mais** gostoso (do) **que** o (bolo) de laranja.
>
> Este bolo é **o mais** gostoso **que** eu alguma vez provei.
> **O bolo mais** gostoso **que** eu alguma vez provei é este aqui.
>
> Este bolo é **o mais** gostoso **de** todos aqui na mesa.
> **O bolo mais** gostoso **de** todos aqui na mesa é este aqui.
>
> Esta padaria tem bolos muito gostosos, mas este aqui é **o mais** gostoso **deles** todos.
> Esta padaria tem bolos muito gostosos, mas **o mais** gostoso **deles** todos é este aqui.

Nos teus três primeiros exemplos, teria de ser o contexto a clarificar o sentido das frases. Por exemplo a Ana prepara-se para cortar uma fatia do bolo de laranja, e o João aponta o bolo de coco e diz:

> Este bolo é **mais** gostoso. [Subentende-se *que esse que tu vais cortar*]

Ou a Ana olha para os bolos sobre a mesa e parece hesitante. Então o João aponta o bolo de coco e diz:

> Este bolo é **o mais** gostoso/**o bolo mais** gostoso é este.

Subentende-se *de todos os bolos da mesa*, mas na minha sensibilidade soa mais natural incluir mesmo *deles todos/de todos*.

O contexto pode também ser fornecido pelo diálogo, mas nestes exemplos é mais natural omitir a palavra *bolo* entre parênteses; e soam-me bem mesmo sem o *de todos*:

> Ana:—Vou comer uma fatia de bolo de laranja.
> João:—Este (bolo) aqui é **mais** gostoso. [Subentende-se *mais gostoso que o de laranja*]
>
> Ana:—Não sei qual destes bolos escolher.
> João:—Este (bolo) aqui é **o mais** gostoso/**o** (bolo) **mais** gostoso é este aqui. [Subentende-se *deles todos*.]

A escolha entre *este é o bolo mais gostoso* e *o bolo mais gostoso é este* depende do que queres enfatizar. Nos exemplos anteriores seria indiferente. Mas nos seguintes há uma forma que eu claramente prefiro:

> Ana:—Este bolo aqui é bom?
> João:—Esse bolo aí!? Esse bolo é **o mais** gostoso que eu comi em toda a minha vida!
>
> Ana (junto à mesa dos bolos):—Qual é **o bolo mais gostoso**?
> João:—Para mim, **o bolo mais gostoso** é este aqui.

“O bolo o mais gostoso” não é gramatical. Creio que os franceses é que falam assim. Poderás ouvi coisas como  “o bolo... o mais gostoso” com uma pausa, mas isso são duas frases incompletas, que é uma coisa que acontece frequentemente em conversa.

Os dois últimos exemplos são possíveis, mas de facto estou com dificuldade a encontrar contextos em que soem naturais. Mas vendo simplesmente o lado gramatical, no primeiro exemplo temos um superlativo; no segundo, um comparativo. Isso fica claro se incluirmos termos de comparação explícitos:

> Gramatical: *O bolo que é **o mais gostoso que eu comi na vida** é este aqui.*
> Não gramatical: *O bolo que é **mais gostoso que eu comi na vida** é este aqui.*
> Gramatical: *O bolo que é **mais gostoso que o de laranja** é este aqui*.
> Não gramatical: *O bolo que é **o mais gostoso que o de laranja** é este aqui*

Onde este tipo de construção mais naturalmente ocorrerá é em perguntas. Por exemplo, o João disse que tinha acabado de provar o bolo mais gostoso que alguma vez tinha comido, e a Ana vai com ele ao pé da mesa e pergunta:

> *Qual é o bolo que é o mais gostoso que tu já comeste?* = *qual destes bolos é que é o mais gostoso que tu já comeste?*

Num contexto semelhante:

> Qual é o bolo que é mais gostoso que o de laranja?